# Show first image and load others async

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous

I have Foxit Quick PDF Library for rendering a multipage PDF to single .bmp files. How to show the first file and load the rest asynchronous? Because if i have a 10 page i have to wait some seconds.

XAML:

```
<Image Name="_bildDruck" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" MaxHeight="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=RegularContent, Mode=OneWay}" MaxWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=RegularContent, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

Render single bmp:

```
DPL.LoadFromFile("C:/Design/aaa.pdf","");
int numpages = DPL.PageCount();
DPL.RenderDocumentToFile(150, 1, numpages, 0, "C:/temp/image.bmp");
```

Load first bmp (executed too late, because every page gets loaded):

```
BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
bitmap.BeginInit();
Uri uri = new Uri("C:/temp/image1.bmp");
bitmap.UriSource = uri;
bitmap.EndInit();
_bildDruck.Source = bitmap;
```

I know that i have to do a async task, but im relative new to this stuff.
Any help?

Comment: The question does not seem to make sense. You have a single BMP file. Which *others* would you load later? You probably want to render different pages of the document seperately into multiple BMPs.

Comment: I have multiple BMPs... BMPs for every single page.. But my renderer is rendering the BMPs snd i have to wait until it renders every BMP. Is there a way to async continue this task, because i want to show the first page in the meanwhile